# Laravel - Can no longer use basic auth

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, jwt

I used the article below to create JWT auth in my laravel project.  But now I can no longer use the Basic auth.  Is there a way to use Basic auth as well?  I need it for my web interface.

https://scotch.io/tutorials/token-based-authentication-for-angularjs-and-laravel-apps

[image: Kernel file]

[image]

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use Validator;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ThrottlesLogins;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;

class AuthController extends Controller
{

use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'getLogout']);
}

protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => 'required|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
    ]);
}

protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);
}
}
```

Route::get('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin');
Route::post('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin');

Update:  after turning the debug on I got the following error:

Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException (E_UNKNOWN)
Trait 'Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers' not found

Comment: Why cannot you use it? What errors do you get? What changes did you make to your `kernel.php` try posting your kernel file

Comment: @zuif - added the kernel file.  I tried signing in with the auth form and it won't let me.  But if I install a sepearate instance of laravel and use the same backend I can login.

Comment: Can you also post your config `auth.php` file, and also post your controller where you are trying to use the basic auth

Comment: @zuif - just added.  Please see attached.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code and put the code itself into your question/answer. Pictures will get deleted over time by most image hosting providers and this means the content of your question/answer is lost. It also prevents other users from copying the code (i.e. when they want to test it).

Comment: @Namoshek - Understood.  Will keep that in mind.  These are just config files not the actual code.

Comment: Hmm. Also post your controller where you are trying to use your basic auth

Comment: @zuif - posted code.  JWT is being handeled by a different controller.

Comment: @user9465677 Hmm, what to say, I know this will not answer your question, but you followed pretty outdated article... `tymondesigns/jwt-auth` is not maintained anymore (please check open issues on github). So since you moved to L5.6 already, I would suggest to modify your approach and try using official Laravel package (Passport), for jwt token authorization. It is much more flexible and what is more important it is still maintained...

Comment: @Bart - I wrote the JWT auth in 2015.  At that time I didn't have a use for the basic auth.  But now I do.  Do you think there are other options such as moving the the current deployment to a subdomain so that I can still use all the APIs and then have a fresh laravel install with different app_key but the same db/backend to support the basic auth?

Comment: @user9465677 you can always move your current app to different domain, but how will this affect your current api clients? This is the question, you can only answer yourself. If it won't do any harm, do it. If not, leave your current domain untouched and start fresh under new subdomain....

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks fine, except to use`Tymon\JWTAuth` you should make these changes

Change the api driver to jwt instead of token, I would have posted the code if you would have posted the code instead of an image and change the default guard to be api.

And for your basic auth you should be able to use it without a problem. Try doing it, if you could not post the code and I'll post the code.

Comment: It didn't work for the basic auth.  May be because the base is is Laravel 5.1.  Even though I had upgraded to 5.6, it doesn't have the same auth capabilities that 5.6 has.  I get a blank page if I type mydomain/auth/login.  I have added the controller code above.   I get Whoops looks like something went wrong message.

Comment: @user9465677 make sure to add `APP_DEBUG=true` to your `.env` file  to see full error description...

Comment: Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException (E_UNKNOWN)
Trait 'Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers' not found